# Debian motd show pending updates

Tags: debian

How can show pending updates in the message of the day on Debian stretch?

Before stretch and in Ubuntu still this is possible via the `update-notifier-common` package. The package got removed in stretch and replaced by `apt-config-auto-update` which however don't provide commands to get the current status of pending updates.

What is the new way to show pending updates in motd on Debian stretch?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably neither the only, nor the best way.  But it should work.

1. Ensure aptitude is installed
2. Get the motd update script to call "aptitude search '~U'"